# Intuitive meaning of unscaled variance in R regression

Tags: regression, standard-error

I've been working on understanding how R calculates the standard error it reports in the `summary()` of a regression generated using `lm()` like:

```
x <- c(1:20)

y1 <- 3 * x + rnorm(length(x), sd = 0.5)
r1 <- lm(y1 ~ x)
s1 <- summary(r1)
s1$coefficients
```

and came across the `s1$cov.unscaled` matrix, which is calculated from the design matrix of the regression like:

```
X <- matrix(c(rep(1, length(x)), x), ncol = 2)
M <- solve(t(X) %*% X)
```

where `M == s1$cov.unscaled`. Since it only depends on `x`, `M` is also the same as `s2$cov.unscaled` in:

```
y2 <- 3 * x + rnorm(length(x), sd = 5)
r2 <- lm(y2 ~ x)
s2 <- summary(r2)
```

where the residual error of the regression is much higher. Together with the residual standard error `s1$sigma`, `M` can then be used to calculate the standard error of the parameter estimates as reported in `s1$coefficients`:

```
sqrt(diag(M) * s1$sigma^2)
```

The meaning of the standard error of a parameter estimate is quite intuitive, and it also makes sense that an estimate of how well the regression fits the data (like `s1$sigma`) would be included in its calculation (i.e. $\widehat{\sigma}^2 (X^{\top}X)^{-1}$). I am having trouble however in understanding intuitively the meaning of `s1$cov.unscaled` (or more generally $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}$), which only depends on `x`, and not on `y1` or `y2`. Is there an intuitive meaning of this construct?

I'd be very grateful for any clarifications or reading suggestions on this matter!

Comment: see also this question for answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267948/intuitive-explanation-of-the-xtx-1-term-in-the-variance-of-least-square