# What is the matrix $(X'\Omega^{-1}X)$ in Generalized Least Square / Weighted Least Square?

Tags: econometrics, generalized-least-squares, wls

What is the matrix $(X'\Omega^{-1}X)$ X) in Generalized Least Square / Weighted Least Square?
[image: //]

More precisely,
We know:
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to ask, because you show us explicitly what $X$ and $\Omega$ are.  Do you need help inverting $\Omega$?  Performing the matrix multiplication?  Something else?

Comment: If you ask for what it represents, it is a weighted version of $X' X$, so look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22501/is-there-an-intuitive-interpretation-of-ata-for-a-data-matrix-a, and also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364554/intuition-behind-xtx-1-in-closed-form-of-w-in-linear-regression,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267948/intuitive-explanation-of-the-xtx-1-term-in-the-variance-of-least-square

Comment: Thanks! Could you also maybe take a look at this question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596299/order-and-rank-conditions-for-identification-with-simultaneous-systems-instrum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, if we have an $n \times k$ matrix $X$, $X'X = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i x_i'$, where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $X$.  How to get from there to where you want to be should be obvious.

As a historical note, in the early days of computers (the 1970s), SAS Institute built the first widely used stats software, in part based on this relationship.  $X$ matrices of any substantial size were too big to fit into memory along with everything else - it wasn't until 1971 that the IBM 360 could have 32K of memory, and 1976 when the high-end version of the IBM 370 reached 1MB, with most computers having far less - which meant calculating $X'X$ the obvious way wasn't possible.   This relationship allowed SAS to read large (for the time) matrices in small blocks of rows and sum up the outer products $x_ix_i'$ to get $X'X$.  This allowed SAS to solve regression problems that were far larger than could fit into memory!

Comment: Thanks! Could you also maybe take a look at this question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596299/order-and-rank-conditions-for-identification-with-simultaneous-systems-instrum

Comment: If this answers (this) question, please accept it, so others will know that it's been answered... acceptably... well!

Comment: Just accepted. It would be great if you can answer the other on as well!

Comment: Your history is off by five years: System/360 supported over 32 Kb by 1966 when a 4 Mb machine was introduced.  Relatively large regression problems were being solved even in the 1950's.  The bottleneck then was computing time.